# Edwards' reasoning for why this contour integral representation of $\zeta (s)$ converges everywhere

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, riemann-zeta

Consider the contour integral
$$\int_C \frac{(-x)^s}{e^x-1}\frac{dx}{x}$$
where the path of integration begins at $\infty$, moves to the left down the positive real axis, circles the origin once in the positive direction, and returns up to the positive real axis to $\infty$. The definition of $(-x)^s$ is $(-x)^s=\exp (s \log (-x))$. $\zeta (s)$ can be represented by
$$\zeta (s)=\frac{\Gamma (1-s)}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{(-x)^s}{e^x-1}\frac{dx}{x}.$$

Now in his book *Riemann's Zeta Function*, Edwards states

> The contour integral clearly converges for all values of $s$ (because $e^x$ grows much faster than $x^s$ as $x\to \infty$).

I don't understand this explanation at all. Using this logic, we can conclude that the integral in
$$\zeta (s) \Gamma (s)=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s}}{e^x-1}\frac{dx}{x}$$
converges for all values of $s$ "since $e^x$ grows much faster than $x^s$", which is clearly nonsense, as the integral converges only for $\Re (s)\gt 1$.

Can someone explain Edwards' reasoning?

Comment: The latter integral has a singularity at $0$ and that's where the condition $\Re s > 1$ is needed; the line integral avoids that by circling the origin so only the behavior at infinity matters for convergence